# Select Rows and have children of said rows as a column using ltree

Tags: json, postgresql, grails-orm, ltree

"Content" table has a column "ltree" - Content items are created with a hierarchy based on this ltree.

For example:

| Title | LTREE |
| --- | --- |
| Record 1 | 1 |
| Record 2 | 1.2 |
| Record 3 | 1.2.3 |

What I'm attempting to do is create a SELECT statement in which I receive a nested response of that records children:

| Title | Children |
| --- | --- |
| Record 1 | {Record 2, {Record 3, {}}} |

The goal is to retrieve a distinct number of "top level" records, as well as the nested children that are assigned to that top level record through the LTREE

I have attempted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, ARRAY(SELECT title FROM content t WHERE t.ltree <@ content.ltree At.ltree != content.ltree) as children
```

Which would provide me

| Title | Children |
| --- | --- |
| Record 1 | {Record 2} |
| Record 2 | {Record 3} |
| Record 3 | `{}` |

However, this will only provide me with a response "1 layer deep", I have yet to find a way to continue to nest the response - and if that would be possible - to then remove Record 2 and Record 3 from the above select as it is present within one of the nested records.

Any suggestions are much appreciated - I'm not entirely in my element when it comes to psql/sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ARRAY_AGG` function to aggregaget a group of inheritance from the current node:

```sql
select t.title, (select array_agg(p.ltree) from content p where p.ltree <@ t.ltree) from content t;
```

This will give you current and all child nodes of the tree like this:

| title | array_agg |
| --- | --- |
| Record 1 | {1,1.2,1.2.3} |
| Record 2 | {1.2,1.2.3} |
| Record 3 | {1.2.3} |

Since this is a tree structure nesting is kind of against common sense, as the tree is actually a nested structure. If you would like to nest rows I would risk saying you gonna end up working with some sort of a stored procedure, as it will require a multi level sub-select. One can try a hierarchical query, but it's a somewhat complicated task at this point.